# Sort an array contains some dates by days order like sunday, monday etc. in php

Tags: php, arrays, date

I have an array with 7 dates.

```
$dates = array(
'2018-03-07', //Wednesday
'2018-03-08', //Thursday
'2018-03-09', //Friday
'2018-03-10', //Saturday
'2018-03-11', //Sunday
'2018-03-12', //Monday
'2018-03-13', //Tuesday
);
```

I want to sort the above array by day wise (Sunday to Saturday order).

The expected output is,

```
 $dates = array(
'2018-03-11', //Sunday
'2018-03-12', //Monday
'2018-03-13', //Tuesday
'2018-03-07', //Wednesday
'2018-03-08', //Thursday
'2018-03-09', //Friday
'2018-03-10', //Saturday
);
```

How to sort like this? Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `usort()` and `date('w')`, to sort your array using the *"Numeric representation of the day of the week"*

```
$dates = array(
'2018-03-07', //Wednesday
'2018-03-08', //Thursday
'2018-03-09', //Friday
'2018-03-10', //Saturday
'2018-03-11', //Sunday
'2018-03-12', //Monday
'2018-03-13', //Tuesday
);

usort($dates, function($a, $b) {
    return date('w',strtotime($a)) - date('w',strtotime($b)) ;
});

print_r($dates);
```

Outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2018-03-11
    [1] => 2018-03-12
    [2] => 2018-03-13
    [3] => 2018-03-07
    [4] => 2018-03-08
    [5] => 2018-03-09
    [6] => 2018-03-10
)
```

[`date('w')`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) returns : 0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday).

Comment: The sort callback shall return a value <0, 0, or a value >0; not `true` or `false`.

Comment: @Arya You're welcome. Be sure to use the last version using `-` not `<` as pointed out by deceze.

Answer (score 0):

```
usort(array, function($a, $b){
    $dayA = date('w', strtotime($a));
    $dayB = date('w', strtotime($b));

    return $dayA < $dayB ? 1 : $dayA === $dayB ? 0 : -1;
});
```

this should work as you asked for